# Какую книгу выбрать для изучения Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, книги

Помогите выбрать книгу для начинающих, на языке **Python3**.

---

Например -

1) **Зед Шоу - Легкий способ выучить Python 3**

Answer (score 2):

- Марк Лутц "**Изучаем python**", в ней изложены все основы языка.
- Марк Лутц "**Программирование на python**" первый и второй тома, там уже говориться о практическом применении языка.
- Так же после лутца на выбор можно более сложное по типу -  Дэвид М. Бизли "**Cookbook**" или Лучано Рамальо "**К вершинам мастерства**".

Ну а дальше уже можно углубиться в изучение фреймворков.